# LINQ to SQL Left Join with empty left part

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I have a method:

```
public Result[] LeftJoin(IQueryable<AEntities> aEntities)
{
    var bEntities = ReaderContext.GetContracts<BEntities>();

    var queryable = from a in aEntities
                    join bEntity in bEntities on a.BId equals bEntity.Id into bTemp
                    from b in bTemp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select new Result { A = a, B = b };

    return ReaderContext.Select(queryable);
}
```

When I call `LeftJoin(ReaderContext.GetContracts<AEntities>())`, this SQL query is executed:

```
SELECT * FROM A
LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON A.BId = B.Id
```

When I call `LeftJoin(new AEntities[0].AsQueryable())`, this SQL query is executed:

```
SELECT * FROM B
```

Both return the correct results.

Why is the second query executed?

Comment: One way to avoid it is calling `ReaderContext.GetContracts<AEntities>().Where(_ => false)` to produce empty IQueryable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one is getting both the `aEntities` and `bEntities` from the DB. The second already has the `aEntities` in the array you passed in and only has to get the `bEntities` from the DB and then does the join in code.